# Java/Android TCP Client issue

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a fully working TCP Server developed in Node.JS that i today use with C# clients, i also tested it with packet sender, and the server has been stable and working for over a month now. I decided to move my client project over to Java, using Android Studio, yea it's really an android app.

I'm doing a Thread to do the networking to prevent UI Freezes.
Here is the code:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket client = new Socket("IP.domain.com", 2097);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                    out.write("test");

                    String serverResponse = in.readLine();
                    
                    cryptitAlert("DEBUG", serverResponse);

                    client.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

Tho i have some issue with it.

Well the server state connections when the Thread are running, but the server really doesn't get any message, as i console log all incomming messages, in addition the socket isn't even closed, so i don't quite understand what's happening here?

I'm not quite sure if the code i have are sending buffers or ASCII's, but the server now currently handle ASCII during development phase, i'm just in need of something simple like this currently.

UPDATE:
getting this error in logcat:

```
2022-08-13 00:29:03.964 2759-5759/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:6)
```

Comment: Have you looked at Logcat to see if you have a stack trace from an exception that you caught?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes check the update

Comment: If you write to an OutputStream this does not mean the data is directly sent. Sockets are internally buffered so only if you call `flush` on the stream the data will be sent.

Comment: Something like this; out.flush(); after .write() ?

Comment: That stack trace is from `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`. I suspect that this is not your app.

Comment: The flush worked. Only issue now is that the in reader doesn't work. There is no errors after i implemented the flush, it got removed by that.

Comment: `out.write("test");` If the server reads lines too you better change that to `out.write("test\n"); flush();`.

Comment: @blackapps no, the server doesn't read lines. But i guess this android app does, so should i add \n to the server response lines?

Comment: Indeed you should and meanwhile you tried ;-)